# Does the FTC apply on a function of two variables?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am doing a project on traffic flow, and am deriving the conservation equation between density and flux. I have got to this line in my calculations, and am unsure how to justify the step.

$$q(x_1,t)-q(x_2,t)=-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\partial q(x,t)}{\partial x} dx $$

Does the FTC apply? I wasn't sure since we have a function of two variables in this case. In all of the sources I have used, they have taken this step as purely trivial, but I would like to know for certain why we are allowed to do this. Out of curiosity, is this always possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be $q(x_2,t) - q(x_1,t)$, not $q(x_1,t)-q(x_2,t)$. Yes fundamental theorem of calculus applies (under mild assumptions that the derivative is continuous that are likely automatically satisfied for your problem) since if we fix time $t$ then we can write $f(x)=q(x,t)$ and $f'(x)$ is the partial derivative you use.

Comment: Yes sorry, my error, the integral was supposed to have a minus sign in front! Many thanks for your help!